# SQL Create View error 'begin'

Tags: sql, view

I'm getting an error with my `BEGIN` keyword.

> 'Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure AdminReport, Line 3 Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'

. Also my "customers.firstname' could not be Bound.

```
   CREATE VIEW [dbo].[AdminReport] 
   AS 
   BEGIN 

     SELECT
        b.bookingID,
        b.totalCost,
        b.bookingDate,
        b.paymentConfirmation,
        c.customersID,
        customers.firstname,
        c.surname,
        c.contactNum,
        paymentConfirmation
    FROM 
        booking b
        INNER JOIN customers c
            ON b.customerID= c.customersID
    Where
        paymentConfirmation = 'False'
    ORDER BY 
        bookingDate ASC

    END

    GO
```

Could someone help please! Thanks.

Comment: `customers.firstname` - Is there a column in `customers` named `firstname`? Why are you referring to it by the table name here, while other columns are referred to by the table alias `c`?

Comment: What's your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your customer.firstname cannot be bound because you are renaming the table as "c" so use c.firstname

is paymentconfirmation from b? If so might as well state it on the query to keep it consistent. Run the select statement by itself and see if it gives you an error.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the BEGIN and END.  They're not needed in CREATE VIEW syntax.
See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp